# How to transfer variable value from Python script to a Bash script

Tags: python, bash

I want to create a package manager for LFS (Linux From Scratch) my idea was to use a Python script to ask for the file and transfer the value to a Bash script but so far I can't transfer the value here's my code

```
import os
import subprocess

path="/sources/"
inputfile=input("please enter input file:")
inputfile1=inputfile
subprocess.call(['bash', 'run.sh', 'inputfile1'])
```

and here is the Bash script (it's quite short because it's just a test)

```
path="hello world"
echo $path
echo $inputfile1
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that call returns a value.  Try reading stdout from it.  see https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess  ie. `result = subprocess.call(...` then `print(result.stdout)`.  welcome aboard.  and... you seem to be wanting to transfer from a bash script's result to Python, the opposite of what your title seems to imply

Comment: search stackoverflow for `python subprocess read stdout` and you'll find tons of answers.  probably a duplicate or 2 of what you are asking for.

Comment: Just to be clear, you do not just want to transfer the value of ˋinputfile1ˋ, you also want to transfer its name? E.g. not “$1=“/tmp/foo/bar” but ˋ$inputfile1=“/tmp/foo/bar”? Are you aware of environment variables and named command line arguments? Is there a reason why you don’t get the input in the bash script, or do the work in the Python script?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
inputfile=input("please enter input file:")
subprocess.call(['bash', 'run.sh', inputfile])
```

If you want to get the output, run:
`subprocess.check_output(['bash', 'run.sh', inputfile])`